# How calculate text size to fill Linear Layout width whith text's line in Android?

Tags: java, android, screen, dpi

I had this issue:

I wanted to add several lines of TextViews to a Linear Layout and calculate text size
to fill it with the text.

It took me several hours researching and I got it.

Is very complicated in Android calculate text size because there are several screens with
different dpi.

I duckduckgoed several hours without success.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from this way:

```
    final float scaledDensity_sp = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
    final float widthPixels = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    float sp = ((widthPixels / scaleI found the solution from this way:

    final float scaledDensity_sp = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
    final float widthPixels = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    float sp = ((widthPixels / scaledDensity_sp) / text_len) * 2;

    et.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, sp);
```

I tested in several screen's sizes (about ten) and works fine in all (portrait and landscape in most of them).

I used the same text_len (the largest) for all lines because I want the same text size for all.dDensity_sp) / text_len) * 2;

```
    et.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, sp);
```

I tested in several screen's sizes (about ten) and works fine in all (portrait and landscape in most of them).

I used the same text_len (the longest) for all lines because I wanted the same text size for all.

Update 19th august 2022:

Today I updated my HUAWEI to EMUI 12.0.0 and I need to add:

```
    // For EMUI 12.0.0
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)    
    {
        sp--;
    }
```

before

```
    et.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, sp);
```